# How to remove onClick query string without reload in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, query-string

I have a state that receives a url as initial data and the idea is when you click on the item's onclick, remove the respective query string

Searching, I even tried with router.push, but the most I got was so far, but with no success.

```
 const reload = router.push('here would be the id?', undefined, {
      shallow: true
    })

    setQueryStrings(reload) // remove query string do item excluído )
```

**State**

```
const initialQueryString = http://localhost:3000/api/accounts?services=10&accountTypes=20
const [queryStrings, setQueryStrings] = useState(initialQueryString)
```

**Handle Delete Item**

```
const handleDeleteItem = (itemId: string) => {
    const items = resultFilters.filter(({ id }) => id !== itemId)
    setFilters(items)
    setQueryStrings(// remove query string deleted item // )
  }
```

The final result, for example, when clicking on the services key item, the url would be

```
http://localhost:3000/api/accounts?accountTypes=20
```

Comment: To clarify, in your scenario you have buttons that directly map to query string parameters and you want to remove the respective parameter from the page's query string when a button is clicked?